# Cable to connect playstation 2 to VGA port

Tags: ps2

I've been trying to find out how to connect my PS2 to my computer monitor, but I can't seem to find the right cable for it. Is is even possible to do this?

[image]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The VGA and Composite/Component standards are not compatible.  If you want to do this, a passive adapter will *not* work.  You need an active analog video converter that can translate between VGA and Composite/Component Video like [this one.](http://www.monoprice.com/products/product.asp?c_id=101&cp_id=10114&cs_id=1011407&p_id=7113&seq=1&format=2)  This adapter requires a Component (Y/Pb/Pr) connection, which the PS2 can provide, if you use the [correct cable](http://www.monoprice.com/products/product.asp?c_id=108&cp_id=10830&cs_id=1083003&p_id=4009&seq=1&format=2).

Active converters usually require power.  The linked converter runs off of wall power, but you'll need a free electrical plug near your monitor/PS2.

Although passive adapters exist that would allow you to plug the two devices together, they only work with specific models of PC video cards that were designed with this application in mind.

Answer (score 4):

Actually, there IS a ps2 video <> VGA cable available, of sorts. It was an option for when they brought out a Linux kit for the PS2. You could either run it through a normal TV (at a pretty low res), or for an extra €25 you could get the cable: PS2 video at one end, VGA + 2x phono sockets (for sound) at the other.

The website I recall them being available from though is now no longer running. You MIGHT get lucky and find one on eBay, or failing that, I've seen cables that have PS2/Nintendo video connectors <> VGA + composite, for about 13GBP also on ebay.

The only thing I recall though, at least for the Linux port, was that the monitor had to be Sync On Green compatible. I also have a feeling it said they **didn't** work for normal PS2 games, due to the PS2 not putting out the right signal. I've no idea if or how well the 3rd party (PS2/Nintendo) cables work.

For an idea of what you actually need, just Google pictures of "PS2 Linux kit", you should be able to see the cable on some of them.

Answer (score 3):

It's easy to connect your PS2 to the PC monitor without any problem.
For this, you need to buy a external TV tuner box. It costs less and give you better resolution.

Here's how to connect:

1. Connect the your PS2 A/V cable to the TV tuner for the source.
2. Plug in your monitor's VGA cable to the TV tuner for the output.

Now, you can play PS games on your monitor. Enjoy!

NOTE: Make sure your external TV tuner supports VGA output.

Comment: +1 Thanks, have been spending a lot of time at frys trying to find something and this will solve my search once and for all.

Answer (score 1):

While no cable allows direct connection between PS2 and VGA, there are a few alternatives you can use, I would recommend getting a PS2 **component** cable (since this allows a higher resolution connection, 480p/576p, depending on region), and getting a component to VGA adapter.

I've been using [this one from DealExtreme (discontinued)](http://www.dealextreme.com/p/component-video-to-vga-adapter-with-pc-sharing-for-psp-2000-ps3-wii-xbox-dvd-10530), which is USB powered (meaning the PS2 itself could provide power, no additional AC adapter needed). It worked great with Wii and PSP and there's no reason why it wouldn't work with PS2.

Component to VGA adapters aren't cheap, running $30 to $50-60, and the image quality probably won't be too high (after all, PS2 software runs at sub HD resolution), and remember that you still have to deal with the audio signal.